# Oracle plsql use of colsep produces different results than a concat

Tags: sqlplus

When I run this query:

```sql
set heading off;
set feedback off;
set linesize 10000;
set newpage NONE;


select id||'|'||template||'|'||CREATED_DATE from SREAPP.ESSLOG_ERR_MESG_TEMPLATES;

exit;
```

I get what I need - pipe delimited records:

```
± |FSA-887 ↑2 U:9 ?:17 ✗| → sqlplus -s "$OMC_USERNAME/$OMC_PASSWORD@sredb1_high" @sql/gettemplates.sql | head -3
1693613217|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: You must enter a value for the purchase order, in-transit shipment, transfer order, or RMA when resending the receipt advice.|01-JUN-23 12.00.00.000000 AM
3474006367|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: null|01-JUN-23 12.00.00.000000 AM
4116411670|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: PscSecurityUpdateCredentialExecutor.updateUserCredential() - Got exception while updating puds proxy user credentials for the user: puds.pscr.anonymous.user and storing it in credential store with user key: PUK#_PSCR_ANONYMOUS_USER|01-JUN-23 12.00.00.000000 AM
```

However, when I instead use a query that says to use a `colsep '|'` It adds a bunch of extract spacing and then wraps.

```sql
set heading off;
set feedback off;
set linesize 10000;
set newpage NONE;
set colsep '|'

select * from SREAPP.ESSLOG_ERR_MESG_TEMPLATES;

exit;
```

Outputs:

```
sqlplus -s "$OMC_USERNAME/$OMC_PASSWORD@sredb1_high" @sql/gettemplates.sql | head -3
1693613217|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: You must enter a value for the purchase order, in-transit shipment, transfer order, or RMA when resending the receipt advice.                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |01-JUN-23 12.00.00.000000 AM                                        |
3474006367|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: {.ess_code} Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request {.request_id}. Job error is: null                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |01-JUN-23 12.00.00.000000 AM                                        |
4116411670|Execution error for request {.request_id}. Reason: PscSecurityUpdateCredentialExecutor.updateUserCredential() - Got exception while updating puds proxy user credentials for the user: puds.pscr.anonymous.user and storing it in credential store with user key: PUK#_PSCR_ANONYMOUS_USER                                                                                                                                   |01-JUN-23 12.00.00.000000 AM
```

How can I get the same results are concatenation using a declared separator, without externally parsing it?                       |

Table definition (for some unexplainable reason, I can't paste it):

[image: table def]

Comment: This seems to be about [tag:sqlplus], not [tag:plsql].

Comment: how are the columns of ESSLOG_ERR_MESG_TEMPLATES defined?